# Office Js: Problems with locales with angular cli prod build

Tags: angular-cli, office-js

I am building an application for Excel add-in with angular and angular-cli

After building the application with `ng build --prod` the following error occurs:

```
Neither the locale, xx-xx, provided by the host app nor the fallback locale en-us are supported.
```

angular/cli   6.2.4
Office Js 1.1.8

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the issue before.  While it says it's a locale issue, it's more of a general issue that Office.js was not able to locate all of the components that it needed.  Locale is just one manifestation thereof.

How are you referencing the Office.js script in your html file?  Are you using the CDN reference, https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js?  If not, could you try with it?